# Upload photo to form in ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code to edit data with a form. I intend to load the form with a photo that I return to the database.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.upd_uten', function(){
  var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");

  $.ajax({  
        url:"updutente.php",  
        method:"POST",
        cache: false,               
        data:{id:id},               
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data1){

      for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        Id = data1[i][0];
        Imagem = data1[i][60];
        
        $('#iduten').val(Id);
        $('#uploaded_image2').val(Imagem);        
      }
      $('#insnovu').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="row g-3 insnovu">
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="iduten" id="iduten">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="centrar" id="uploaded_image2" name="uploaded_image2">
    <img src="../assets/utente/" class="img-thumbnail" >
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

This way it doesn't load the image.
I've also tried inside ajax to put the following code:

```
$('#uploaded_image2').val('<img src="../assets/utente/',Imagem,'" class="img-thumbnail" >');
```

But it also doesn't load the image inside the div.

Can you help to solve the problem?

Comment: You should use "+" operator instead of commas. Commas here represent multiple parameters to val() function. Also a suggestion, please don't use hard coded indexes on response instead send key value response from backend to avoid guess work/buggy code

Comment: @Yousaf Hassan I used the most as indicated, but it doesn't return the image either. `$('#uploaded_image2').val('<img src="../assets/utente/'+Imagem+'" class="img-thumbnail" >');`